# Using datetime parameters in a stored procedure SQL Server 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling with how to pass datetime parameters into a stored procedure.  This is the example I'm working with. I commented out the declaring of the variables, because if I declare them it doesn't let me pass them in when I execute, but if I don't declare them, I can't execute it. Please help!

```
    --The Create Procedure Code
    CREATE PROCEDURE users.my_test
    AS

    --declare @startdatetime datetime = '03-20-2019'
    --declare @enddatetime datetime = '05-20-2019'
    SELECT datediff(mi,@startdatetime,@enddatetime)
    GO

    --The execution Code
    exec users.my_test
    @startdatetime = '03-31-2019', @enddatetime = '07/03/2019'
    GO
```

Comment: What you're doing here is defined two **internal** variables for the stored procedure - those are *not* parameters that can be set when calling the procedure! Parameters must be declared right *after* the stored procedure name, and with a leading  `@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE users.my_test
 @startdatetime datetime ,
 @enddatetime datetime 
AS

--declare @startdatetime datetime = '03-20-2019'
--declare @enddatetime datetime = '05-20-2019'
SELECT datediff(mi,@startdatetime,@enddatetime)
GO
```